# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin Failed

Tags: maven

After one day effort and reading many topics about that, I have still the problem! I use Debian 8 jessie and used the below command to install maven:

```
apt-get install maven
```

and this is th result of this command: `mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-4-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I also used this : `git clone https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki.git`

to get the bliki. and I went to it's directory and tried this command:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

but i got this results:

```
root@localhost:/home/m/info.bliki.wiki# mvn install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 4 modules...
[INFO] Installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]   ... total of 4 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Bliki POM
[INFO] Bliki (Core)
[INFO] Bliki (PDF)
[INFO] Bliki (Addons)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Bliki POM 3.1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) @ bliki ---
[INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.0:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ bliki ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ bliki ---
[INFO] Installing /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/info/bliki/wiki/bliki/3.1.1-SNAPSHOT/bliki-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Bliki (Core) 3.1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (git submodule update) @ bliki-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ bliki-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 25 resources
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ bliki-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 273 source files to /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ bliki-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 35 resources
[INFO] Copying 141 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ bliki-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 95 source files to /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/api/query/ParseTest.java:[15,9] cannot access java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
  class file for java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/extensions/scribunto/engine/lua/LuaTestBase.java:[65,17] cannot access java.util.Optional
  class file for java.util.Optional not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[12,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalDouble
  class file for java.util.OptionalDouble not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[20,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalInt
  class file for java.util.OptionalInt not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[25,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalLong
  class file for java.util.OptionalLong not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[31,9] cannot access java.time.ZonedDateTime
  class file for java.time.ZonedDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[36,9] cannot access java.time.LocalDateTime
  class file for java.time.LocalDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[41,9] cannot access java.time.OffsetDateTime
  class file for java.time.OffsetDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[46,9] cannot access java.time.OffsetTime
  class file for java.time.OffsetTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[51,9] cannot access java.time.LocalTime
  class file for java.time.LocalTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[56,9] cannot access java.time.LocalDate
  class file for java.time.LocalDate not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[62,9] cannot access java.util.stream.Stream
  class file for java.util.stream.Stream not found
[INFO] 12 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Bliki POM ......................................... SUCCESS [3.093s]
[INFO] Bliki (Core) ...................................... FAILURE [14.456s]
[INFO] Bliki (PDF) ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Bliki (Addons) .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.122s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 30 21:30:18 IRST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project bliki-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/api/query/ParseTest.java:[15,9] cannot access java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
[ERROR] class file for java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/extensions/scribunto/engine/lua/LuaTestBase.java:[65,17] cannot access java.util.Optional
[ERROR] class file for java.util.Optional not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[12,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalDouble
[ERROR] class file for java.util.OptionalDouble not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[20,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalInt
[ERROR] class file for java.util.OptionalInt not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[25,9] cannot access java.util.OptionalLong
[ERROR] class file for java.util.OptionalLong not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[31,9] cannot access java.time.ZonedDateTime
[ERROR] class file for java.time.ZonedDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[36,9] cannot access java.time.LocalDateTime
[ERROR] class file for java.time.LocalDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[41,9] cannot access java.time.OffsetDateTime
[ERROR] class file for java.time.OffsetDateTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[46,9] cannot access java.time.OffsetTime
[ERROR] class file for java.time.OffsetTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[51,9] cannot access java.time.LocalTime
[ERROR] class file for java.time.LocalTime not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[56,9] cannot access java.time.LocalDate
[ERROR] class file for java.time.LocalDate not found
[ERROR] /home/m/info.bliki.wiki/bliki-core/src/test/java/info/bliki/wiki/filter/HTTPUrlFilterTest.java:[62,9] cannot access java.util.stream.Stream
[ERROR] class file for java.util.stream.Stream not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :bliki-core
```

I am newbie in Linux and don't know alot about it's commands and Errors! I also Added these lines to my pom.XML file but it had no sense!

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

This is my pom.XML file contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Bliki POM</name>
    <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>
        The Bliki API is a Java-based Wiki to HTML renderer with MediaWiki syntax support.
    </description>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki</url>

    <organization>
        <name>Java Wikipedia API (Bliki engine)</name>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki</url>
    </organization>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>axelclk</id>
            <name>Axel Kramer</name>
        </developer>

        <developer>
            <id>jberkel</id>
            <name>Jan Berkel</name>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>master</tag>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/src</url>
    </scm>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>Bitbucket</system>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/issues</url>
    </issueManagement>

    <ciManagement>
        <url>https://drone.io/bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki</url>
    </ciManagement>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Eclipse Public License 1.0</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/eclipse-1.0.php</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
        <license>
            <name>GNU Lesser General Public License - v 2.1 or later</name>
            <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <modules>
        <module>bliki-core</module>
        <module>bliki-pdf</module>
        <module>bliki-addons</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
                <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
                <artifactId>bliki-pdf</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
                <artifactId>bliki-addons</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.luaj</groupId>
                <artifactId>luaj-jse</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                <version>10.12.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.17</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.betamax</groupId>
                <artifactId>betamax-junit</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Werror</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.6</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <serverId>sonatype-oss-staging</serverId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=simple -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <!--<excludedGroups>info.bliki.annotations.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-staging</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Java version 1.7.
`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`, `java.util.Optional`, `java.util.OptionalDouble`, `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, `etc` are all new features introduced in Java 1.8.  They are not present in Java 1.7.
To get rid of these errors, update your Java version to 1.8.

Comment: i have installed java from synaptic. I don't know how can I upgrade it? when I try install command it says you have installed the last version of it!

Comment: Looks like synaptic's highest version of java is 1.7. You will have to update your java using a different approach. Found this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHJ88jYtgjE). I hope this should help.

Comment: Can you please upvote since the solution worked for you.

Comment: Sorry I am a new user and don't access to it :(